# How to extract number plates from a video of moving vehicles?

Tags: video, ocr, detection

I am working on a project to detect and **extract** vehicle number plates from a video, and saving the number plates in a text file. I have read a lot of research papers and supporting videos, but I still don't see the correct direction to make my project work. Is there any source code/material available where it's all already done? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your programming language allows running external programs (as a **Process** or similar name)...

1) Get **Tesseract OCR** if available for your operating system (I'm on Windows).

2) After installing via `setup.exe`, test on terminal window  with [a basic image](https://arturshams.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/sample1.jpg).
 Tesseract outputs to a text file.

3) If above works well then use your programming language to...

- Run `Tesseract.exe` as an external **Process** (*eg via Java, C#, C++, Python, ActionScript*).
- Grab a snapshot of a video frame into a `Bitmap` variable.
- Convert bitmap to bytearray (find an **Image** or **Bitmap** API command like `myBitmap.getBytes();`...).
- Use **stdin** to send the (image) bytes to Tesseract, which itself gives back text results via **stdout**.
- Use **stdout** to read the Tesseract output or store into some `String` variable.